# REGEX Extract Amount Without Currency

Tags: sql, regex, presto

```
SELECT
    ocr_text,
    bucket,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT('-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?', ocr_text)
FROM temp
```

I am trying to extract amounts from a string that will not have currency present. Any number that does not have decimals should not match. Commas should be allowed assuming they follow the correct rules (at hundreds marker)

```
56         no       (missing decimals)
56.45      yes  
120        no       (missing decimals)
120.00     yes
1200.00    yes
1,200.00   yes
1,200      no       (missing decimals)
1200       no       (missing decimals)
134.5      no       (decimal not followed by 2 digits)
23,00.00   no       (invalid comma location)
```

I'm a noob to REGEX so I know my above statement already does not meet the criteria i've listed. However, i'm already stuck getting the error `(INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT) premature end of char-class` on my `REGEX_EXTRACT` line

---

Can someone point me in the right direction? How can I resolve my current issue? How can I modify to correctly incorporate the other criteria listed?

Comment: To be fair to you, there are only about five people in the world who understand regular expressions. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is probably considered one of the five `:-)`

Comment: Yes well he is from a region of the world where lots of geniuses come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general regex pattern for a positive/negative number with two decimal places and optional thousands comma separators:

```
(?<!\S)(?:-?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2}))(?!\S)
```

### Demo

Your updated query:

```
SELECT
    ocr_text,
    bucket,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(ocr_text, '(?<!\S)(?:-?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2}))(?!\S)')
FROM temp;
```

From the Presto docs I read, it supposedly supports Java's regex syntax.  In the event that lookarounds are not working, you may try this version:

```
SELECT
    ocr_text,
    bucket,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(ocr_text, '(\s|^)(?:-?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2}))(\s|$)')
FROM temp;
```

Comment: @urdearboy Please reload the page and try the second version of my query.  That should be working for you with no issues.

Comment: same issue with your updated version :(. +1 from new none-the-less for your time

Comment: @urdearboy Found your other problem.  The syntax of `REGEXP_EXTRACT` is that the input comes _first_, and the regex pattern _second_.  Try it again to see if it is working now.

Comment: Just for the record, can you check both versions and comment here which ones are working for you?

Comment: They actually both worked. Ran query with both regex and columns were equal

Answer (score 2):

REGEXP_EXTRACT('^[-]?(\d*.\d*)', ocr_text)

Pattern: `^[-]?(\d*\.\d*)`

**Explanation**:

`^` - Start of line

`[-]?` - With or without negative dash (-)

`\d*` - 0 or more digits

`\.` - a decimal (escaped, because in regex decimals are considered special characters)

`\d*` - 0 or more digits (the decimal part);

`$` - End of the line.

Bonus tip: There are helpful tools online to [test your regex](https://regex101.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

The Below code works to extract the value like all numbers but it catches all, only specific to certain alphabets its not working well. Anyone, please suggest well.

```
-?\d+\.?\d*
```

I have done work on NLP using Regex.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30741312)